# auto.arima() seemingly selects different models given same data

Tags: r, arima

I was trying something like the `auto.arima` example in https://otexts.com/fpp2/lagged-predictors.html and noticed I get different results depending on whether I specify (all) rows of data explicitly or not.  MWE:

```
library(forecast); library(fpp2)
nrow(insurance)
auto.arima(insurance[,1], xreg=insurance[,2], stationary=TRUE)
auto.arima(insurance[1:40,1], xreg=insurance[1:40,2], stationary=TRUE)
```

The `nrow(insurance)` shows there are 40 rows, so I'd think `insurance[,1]` would be the same as `insurance[1:40,1]`, and similarly for the second column.  Yet, the first way results in a "Regression with ARIMA(3,0,0) errors" whereas the second way results in a "Regression with ARIMA(1,0,2) errors."

Why do these seemingly equivalent calls result in different selected models?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `insurance[,1]` has labels and `insurance[1:40,1]` does not. If you pass `as.numeric(insurance[,1])` you will actually receive "ARIMA(1,0,2)". So I bet it has to do with if the first argument has labels or not...Also note that it doesn't matter if `xreg=insurance[,2]` or `xreg=insurance[1:40,2]` they both will work

Answer (score 0):

Corey nudged me in the right direction: `insurance[,1]` is a "time series" whereas `insurance[1:40,1]` is numeric.  That is, `is.ts(insurance[,1])` is `TRUE` but `is.ts(insurance[1:40,1])` is `FALSE`.  The `forecast` package has a `subset` function that preserves the time series structure, so `is.ts(subset(insurance[,1],start=1,end=40))` is `TRUE` and

```
auto.arima(subset(insurance[,1],start=1,end=40), 
           xreg=subset(insurance[,2],start=1,end=40), stationary=TRUE)
```

gives the same output as the first version in my question (with `insurance[,1]` and `insurance[,2]`).

I think that explains "why" at least superficially, although I don't understand
1) why the time series structure changes the result here (since there doesn't seem to be any seasonality in the selected models?), and 
2) why in the linked example Hyndman uses `insurance[4:40,1]` instead of his own `subset()` function from his `forecast` package?
I'll wait to see if somebody wants to answer those "deeper" questions, otherwise I'll probably accept this answer.